# super(context, textviewid); java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

Trying to figure out how to pass the super constructor to stop this `NPE`, can anyone help?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        ((DownloadFragment) downloads).refreshlist();
    }
}
```

**DownloadFragment.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AdapterItem> {
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textviewid) {
        super(context, textviewid); // NPE here
    }

    public void refreshlist() {
        items.clear();
        adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), 0);
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Exception :**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:104)
at com.DownloadFragment$MyAdapter.<init>(DownloadFragment.java:142)
at com.DownloadFragment.refreshlist(DownloadFragment.java:479)
at com.MainActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(MainActivity.java:387)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onWindowFocusChanged(PhoneWindow.java:2466)
at android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:7456)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:935)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3264)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Now next line in refreshList() method is null after doing this.

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), 0);
}

DownloadFragment.java

```
Cursor a = mDbHelper.getEachDownload(2);
```

Comment: Please post a full stack trace.

Comment: Where have you initialized "adapter" ?

Comment: What are your intentions of using onWindowFocusChanged? You don't generally override this. Perhaps there is another lifecycle callback you should be using which we could suggest based on your intentions?

Comment: public class DownloadFragment extends SherlockListFragment {


 public MyAdapter adapter;

Comment: Could you test getActivity() method? Maybe null. Please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because you're passing it a null context.

Try:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        ((DownloadFragment) downloads).refreshlist(this);
    }
}
```

DownloadFragment.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AdapterItem> {
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textviewid) {
        super(context, textviewid); // NPE here
    }

    public void refreshlist(Context context) {
        items.clear();
        adapter = new MyAdapter(context, 0);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Are you trying to refresh your adapter with new data? Have you tried notifyDataSetChanged()?

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus); 
    if (hasFocus) { 
       DownloadFragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes as I created MainActivity to be singleTask so multiple instances do not require to be created and list refreshes on focus.

Comment: 10-31 17:11:00.620: E/AndroidRuntime(15909): java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

  if (hasFocus) {
   DownloadFragment.adapter.notify();
   DownloadFragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
 }

Comment: DownloadFragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); worked thank you!

Answer (score 0):

getActivity() method in Fragment class returns null until it has attached to the Activity i.e. until onAttach(Activity) method is invoked. so better to create object for MyAdapter class in onActivityCreated() method of Fragment.

try this...

```
public class DownloadFragment extends Fragment {
    private MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some examples please?

Comment: you have to call refreshList() method when Fragment is attached to Activity only...

Comment: Now next line in refreshList() Cursor a = mDbHelper.getEachDownload(2); method is null after doing this. 

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
 adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), 0);
}

Comment: your code is unreadable here. edit your question and post there

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter should like this

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class SmartListAdapterWithHolder extends ArrayAdapter<AdapterItem> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> items;

    public SmartListAdapterWithHolder(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<AdapterItem> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ArrayList<AdapterItem> getSmartListItems() {
        return items;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        Log.v("SmartListAdapter", observer.toString());
        super.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        return convertView;
    }

}
```